# Encrypt/decrypt last 64 KB of file

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am trying to encrypt/decypt last 64 KB of a file, but one of the file folder is missing from the encrypted file. Here I am trying to implement on a zip file. Currently here are 3 folders in the zip file and at the resulted zip, it is only showing two folder. One of the folder is missing. I think it is missing some bytes. Here is my code:

```
static void encryptLast64KB(String inputPath, String outputPath)
throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {


    File myFile = new File(inputPath);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
    BufferedOutputStream bus = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(),
            "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);

    int b = 0;
    byte[] d = new byte[65536];

    int offset = 0;

    byte[] encVal = null;

    while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {

        offset = offset + b;
        Log.d(TAG, "Offset: "+offset);
        Log.d(TAG, "b: "+b);
        if((offset)>=myFile.length())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "last 64 Kbytes");

            try {
                encVal = cipher.doFinal(d);
                Log.d(TAG, "encVal: "+encVal);
                bus.write(encVal);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "rest of the bytes");
            bus.write(d);
        }


        bus.flush();
        bus.close();
        fis.close();
    }


}
```

Please check..

[Edited]
Added decryption code for decrypting last 64 KB.

```
 static byte[] decryptLast64KBytes(String inputPath) throws IOException,
NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
InvalidKeyException {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputPath);

        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] iv = new byte[] { '3', 'd', '0', 'c', 'd', '7', 'A', '9', '7', 'e', '2', '0', 'b', 'x', 'g', 'y' };
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks, ivParameterSpec);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);

        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int count =0;

        int offset = 0;
        while((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            offset = offset + b;
            Log.d(TAG, "Offset: "+offset);
            Log.d(TAG, "b: "+b);
            if((offset)>=fis.available())
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "last 64 Kbytes");
                while((b = cis.read(d, offset, offset+b))!=-1)
                {
                    bos.write(d);
                    offset = offset + b;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "rest of the bytes");
                bos.write(d);
            }

        }

        byte[] completeBytes = bos.toByteArray();
        cis.close();
        return completeBytes;

}
```

Comment: Why encrypt only the last chunk of data? Btw. it will be almost always less than 64kB, for example if your file is 70kB, it'll be likely only about 5kB. It is also impossible to know where the encrypted portion starts given the contract for `read` which allows that less than the requested number of bytes is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you want to encrypt a text message that is not multiples of 8-byte blocks, the text message must be **padded** with additional bytes to make the text message to be multiples of 8-byte blocks.

Try

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

With an initialization vector :

```
byte[] iv = new byte[] { '3', 'd', '0', 'c', 'd', '7', 'A', '9', '7', 'e', '2', '0', 'b', 'x', 'g', 'y' };
IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
```

Small comment : according to me, your byte array is too big, 1024 should be ok

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
```

Note that you could use CipherOutputStream and CipherInputStream to hide the details of encrypting and writing/reading the bytes. I would actually recommend that for these requirements.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFileName);
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot @Antho, Encryption is working fine now...But the problem still there in decryption

Comment: Try to use the following : FileOutputStream.write(byte[] b, int off, int len)"
Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this file output stream.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't encrypt the last 64KB. It encrypts the last chunk, whatever its size, resulting from all the prior reads. If you want the last 64KB, God knows why, you have to seek() or skip() to the appropriate value, that is to say the file length minus 64KB.